# Where did the higgs field energy go when it broke symmetry

Tags: higgs

Where did the Higgs field energy go when it broke symmetry and fell into its ground state. If it did that in the whole universe huge amounts of energy must've been released.

Comment: Nevermind, it just gave masses to WZ-Bosons. That was the whole point of introducing it, right?

Comment: You got it. Unfortunately, the reason for its introduction is also the reason for the incredible boringness of the Higgs. If the standard model is anywhere close to a good model (and by now it seems that way), it kind of has to be there... and it is. Not much was learned and certainly next to nothing gained for model building from the discovery of the Higgs.

Comment: There is no "time when the symmetry was broken", this is a popular misconception, see [this question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/119921/50583) - the "brokenness" is just neglegible above certain energy scales.